# Python websocket-client reconnect after server restart

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I want to implement a client-server application with Python(client) and Spring Boot(Server) over websockets. I want client to try to connect server even if it is stopped, has network problems etc.

```
import time
from threading import Thread, Event

import rel
import stomper
import websocket
import logging

class ClientSocket:
 def __init__(self):
    self.opened = None
    self.thread = None
    self.opened = False
    self.try_connecting = Event()
    self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:8080/socket",
                                     header={
                                         'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.ey'},
                                     on_open=self.on_open,
                                     on_message=self.on_message,
                                     on_error=self.on_error,
                                     on_close=self.on_close)
    # self.rel = rel
    self.ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel)
    rel.signal(2, rel.abort)  # Keyboard Interrupt
    rel.dispatch()

def on_message(self, ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(self, ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(self, ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("### closed ###")
    if self.opened:
        self.connect_abort_server()
    if not self.try_connecting.is_set():
        self.try_connecting.set()
        self.auto_reconnect()

def on_open(self, ws):
    self.opened = True
    if self.try_connecting.is_set():
        self.try_connecting.clear()
    print("Opened connection")
    time.sleep(2)
    ws.send("CONNECT\naccept-version:1.0,1.1,2.0\n\n\x00\n")

    # Subscribing to all required desitnations.
    sub = stomper.subscribe("/user/queue/reply", "clientuniqueId", ack="auto")
    ws.send(sub)

def connect_abort_server(self):
    self.opened = False
    rel.abort()
    self.ws.close()
    self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:8080/socket",
                                     header={
                                         'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.ey'},
                                     on_open=self.on_open,
                                     on_message=self.on_message,
                                     on_error=self.on_error,
                                     on_close=self.on_close)

def thread_func(self):
    while self.try_connecting.is_set():
        try:
            self.ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel)  # Set dispatcher to automatic reconnection
            # self.rel.signal(2, self.rel.abort)  # Keyboard Interrupt
            # rel.dispatch()
            time.sleep(2)
            print('Worker thread running...')
        except ConnectionResetError:
            print("==> ConnectionResetError")
            pass
    print('Worker closing down')

def auto_reconnect(self):
    self.thread = Thread(target=self.thread_func())
    self.thread.daemon = True
    time.sleep(2)
    self.thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   LOG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
   logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=LOG_FORMAT)
   client_socket = ClientSocket()
```

In above:

- Case 1: Server is not working and client tries to connect ✔️
- Case 2: Server starts working and client connects ✔️
- Case 3: Server is stopped and client tries to connect **x**

In the 3rd case after server closed, `on_open` method is invoked very oddly. Is there any solution or different way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After release `1.4.0` of [websocket-client](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client), the problem is fixed. You don't even need to use thread in order to provide continuous tries for reconnecting to server.

```
class ClientSocket:
    def __init__(self):
        self.opened = False
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:8080/socket",
                                         header={
                                             'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9'},
                                         on_open=self.on_open,
                                         on_message=self.on_message,
                                         on_error=self.on_error,
                                         on_close=self.on_close)
        self.ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel)
        rel.signal(2, rel.abort)  # Keyboard Interrupt
        rel.dispatch()

    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        print(message)

    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        print(error)

    def on_close(self, ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
        print("### closed ###")
        rel.abort()
        self.ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel)
        rel.signal(2, rel.abort)
        rel.dispatch()

    def on_open(self, ws):
        print("Opened connection")
        time.sleep(2)
        ws.send("CONNECT\naccept-version:1.0,1.1,2.0\n\n\x00\n")

        # Subscribing to all required desitnations.
        sub = stomper.subscribe("/user/queue/reply", "clientuniqueId", ack="auto")
        ws.send(sub)
```